How to Override an Existing Action to Add a Custom Domain
I'm working on an Odoo module where I need to modify an existing action to add a custom domain. Specifically, I want to filter out subtasks based on a custom boolean field display_under_tasks in the project_project model. If display_under_tasks is True, I want to display subtasks in the Kanban and list views. If display_under_tasks is False, subtasks should be hidden.
To identify if a task is a subtask, I check if the parent_id field is not null.
Here is my current code in project_task_views.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
<record id="custom_action_project_task_all" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Custom Tasks</field>
    <field name="res_model">project.task</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form,calendar,pivot,graph,activity</field>
    <field name="domain">[('parent_id', '=', False), ('project_id.display_under_tasks', '=', True)]</field>
    <field name="context">{ 'default_project_id': active_id, 'show_project_update': True }</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="project.view_task_search_form"/>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            No tasks found. Let's create one!
        </p>
        <p>
            Keep track of the progress of your tasks from creation to completion.
            <br/>
            Collaborate efficiently by chatting in real-time or via email.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>

<!--Inherited Form view project_task_form-->
<record id="project_task_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">project.task.form.inherit.wsl_task_overdue_email_odoo</field>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='user_ids']" position="after">
            <field name="completed_task" invisible="1"/>
        </xpath>

        <xpath expr="//header" position="inside">
            <button name="action_task_completed" string="Task Completed"
                    type="object" class="oe_highlight"
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('completed_task','!=',False)]}"/>

        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('oe_button_box')]" position="before">
            <widget name="web_ribbon" title="Completed" bg_color="bg-success"
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('completed_task', '=', False)]}"/>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>

<!--Inherited the search filter to add 2 more fields in the tree search form-->
<record id="project_task_view_search" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">project.task.search.inherit.wsl_task_overdue_email_odoo</field>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_search_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='rating_last_text']" position="after">
            <field name="completed_task"/>
        </xpath>

        <xpath expr="//filter[@name='stage']" position="after">
            <filter string="Mise a jour" name="group_by_write_date" context="{'group_by': 'write_date'}"/>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//filter[@name='stage']" position="after">
            <filter string="Hide Subtasks" name="hide_subtasks"
                    domain="[('parent_id', '=', False), ('project_id.display_under_tasks', '=', True)]"/>
        </xpath>

        <xpath expr="//filter[@name='unassigned']" position="after">
            <filter string="Completed" name="completed_task"
                    domain="[('completed_task','=',True)]"/>
            <filter string="Not Completed" name="not_completed_task"
                    domain="[('completed_task','!=',True)]"/>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>

It seems that I'm not correctly overriding the default action. What is the correct way to override an existing action in Odoo to add a custom domain?

You need to use the external ID to override the original action, check this answer

yes at first i did as you said in that answer but i faced this error
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "name" of relation "ir_act_window" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (670, null, 1, 1, ir.actions.act_window, action, list,form, null, null, 2024-07-09 08:28:50.426868, 2024-07-09 08:28:50.426868, null, null, 80, null, [('parent_id', '=', False), ('project_id.display_under_tasks', '..., {}, null, current, tree,form, null, null).

It works and you can find an example in the website module which overrides a base module action domain. Which external id did you use?

Probably just the module dependency missing and odoo tries to create the action without required fields. Or the action was removed the used odoo version and you have to find the right one.

this the external id project.act_project_project_2_project_task_all as shown in odoo application

i don't know how it worked , but it worked even without adding project.project to the dependencies...
